# How to install packages locally in ruby and share bundle without having to rebundle?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundle

So I have a ruby project that I want to share with some friends over dropbox. So I'm running

> bundle install --standalone

but once it's ran upon download, its running into this issue

> Reason: image not found - /Users/kimsley/xsios/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.7.9/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.bundle

This error happens to all bundle files.

Comment: `--standalone` requires arguments if you're using groups - which may be the source of some of your problems.

Comment: @thisischuck how should i specify the groups?

Comment: In a space separated list, checkout the documentation: https://bundler.io/v1.1/man/bundle-install.1.html